# Drag & Drop event not working - dragging an image onto another image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have two images `.tape` & `.still`.

`.tape` is a div with a background-image. When I drag and drop the `.tape` image over the `.still` image, I am trying to run the Javascript code below (under the `//Drag & Drop Event` comment in **main.js**).

Tried a number of fixes and I can't get this to work - any solutions would be great!

**index.html**

```
<div id="tape" draggable="true"></div>

<img src="./assets/img/still.png" class="still" ondrop="drop(event)">

<img src="./assets/img/vhstwo.gif" class="vhstwo" onload="fadeIn(this)" style="display:none;">
```

**style.css**

```
#tape {
     background-image: url('./img/trueromance.png');
     background-size: 150px;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     width: 150px;
     height: 220px;
     position: absolute;
     margin: auto;
     left: 0;
     right: 580px;
     top: 325.5px;
     z-index: 3000;
}
```

**main.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //Drag & Drop Event 
  function drag(ev) {
    setTimeout(function() { $(".vhstwo").fadeIn(500); }, 8800);
    $(".still").fadeIn(0); 
  }

    //Custom Ghost Image 
    document.getElementById("tape").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
       e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 200);
        }, false);
       var img = document.createElement("img");
       img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/FLqpRMq.png";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allowdrop on the target divs :

```
 function allowDrop(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault();
 };

 function drop(ev) {
   alert("dosomethingondrop");
 }

 function drag(ev) {
   setTimeout(function() {
     $(".vhstwo").fadeIn(500);
   }, 8800);
   $(".still").fadeIn(0);
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".vhstwo").one("load", function(e) {
     var el = $(this);
     $(function() {
       el.fadeIn(500);
     });
   }).each(function() {
     if (this.complete) $(this).load();
   });
   //Custom Ghost Image 
   document.getElementById("tape").addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {
     e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 200);
   }, false);
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/FLqpRMq.png";

 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Tintin37/j7r5cgo6/